# CSS border issue with background-color

Tags: html, css

[image]

Why thin outline of background color apply inside(I mark with red color in picture). Here is the codepen example [show code on codepen](https://codepen.io/robin_diu/full/poyMaxz)

I want `3px border` outside of `img` with `border-radius: 50%`, everything is working fine but showing the outline(unwanted) i mark on the pic.

How can i solve this unexpected issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply background color in `img` tag

```
img {
  background:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are issues in border when you put it inside the `img` tag there is that thin outline.

You can do an alternative by using `box-shadow` css property.

```
box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 4px #fff;
```

that should work.